# Too fast closure of proposals on Area51

Tags: discussion, area-51

I see that many legitimate proposals are closed very quickly (often by the same people). Why? Shouldn't some more time be given to proposals?

For instance, take this one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21699/psychologist-for-programmers

A spoof? Possible.

Will *eventually* not result in a useful, productive, or viable Q&A site? Almost sure.

However, closing it in such a short time after the creation seems just excess of zealotry to me.

Comment: From your description, I was expecting a timeframe of maybe 30 minutes, not the two days that it actually was.

Comment: *"Don't you think it's a bit dangerous to get advice from programmers of all people about fighting depression and other psychological problems? shouldn't you look for advice from, I don't know, maybe a psychotherapist? (I'm going to have a programmer fix the breaks on my car now, auto mechanics are over-rated)"* that's the actual problem with this proposal, even when cars are run by computers.

Answer (score 10):

[If it were done when 'tis done, then 'twere well it were done quickly](http://www.nosweatshakespeare.com/quotes/soliloquies/macbeth-done-when-done.htm).

Personally, I would *rather* they close sites quickly, if they're going to at all - so people don't invest a lot of time in them.